# How can I connect to Sqlite3 database over SSH using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, ssh, database-connection

I need to connect to a Sqlite3 database in a Linux box over SSH. I tried to  connect through SSH and then connect to database separately but that did not work. That only connected to the Linux box but made another database (instead of connect) in the local computer where Python is running. I tried to search for but could not find any solution to this. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can [forward the SQLite3 port](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding), you can point python to the forwarded port and it will just work. You may want to set up [rqlite](https://github.com/rqlite/rqlite) to expose your sqlite3 database over TCP easily.

Comment: What do you mean by "the SQLite3 port" @hd1? Sqlite doesn't use a client / server system with ports, so [there is no "SQLite3 port"](https://www.quora.com/What-port-does-SQLite-use). Or did I miss something?

Comment: rqlite, linked to in my answer will provide that, @Basj